# Address LAN computers by name over Open VPN

Tags: networking, openvpn, smb, cifs, broadcast

Using OpenVPN client on Windows 7 laptop to access my home network. Workgroup on the laptop is "MyWorkgroup".

Home network:
Wifi router on 192.168.1.1 - Linksys EA6500 with  USB hard drive plugged into its USB port.
Raspberry Pi on 192.168.1.4 set up as VPN server, plugged into the router.

Linksys allow you to name their disk server - say MyServer - but not change the workgroup - always just "workgroup". I'm guessing they have some Linux inside, but there is no way of getting at it or its configuration files.

The Linksys router acts as a server for the USB disk.
When I type 
smb://MyServer/MyHardDisk into the Pi's (Raspbian/Debian) file browser I can access the hard disk, and MyServer appears in the GUI file browser.
When I connect my laptop to my home network and type
\\MyServer\MyHardDisk into a windows file browser I can access the disk, and  MyServer appears in the GUI network browser.

However when I connect the laptop from outside using OpenVPN I can't access files in a file browser using \\MyServer\MyHardDisk, I must type:
\\192.168.1.1\MyHardDisk to get at my files. As well MyServer doesn't appear in the Network file browser.

Searching around, one site said that NetBIOS doesn't cross a VPN, you must set up a WINS server. Is that correct? Another says you need windows broadcast. Another page showed a screen grab of the OpenVPN client's Network browser with all the samba shares in the LAN showing; however it was hazy on the details of how to make it happen - but it must be possible.

What changes do I make to access the file server (the router) by name rather than IP address? And see it in the windows Network browser?

Tried many tips from all over the internet regarding changing the PI VPN server's /etc/openvpn/server.conf file: pushing DNS severs, pushing WINS servers, adding routes etc. Tried changing the /etc/samba/smb.conf file: changing workgroup, enabling WINS, putting in IP address of WINS server (tried .1 router and .4 Pi). No luck.

As you might guess, I don't know much about Linux, even less about OpenVPN, set it all up from internet tutorials.

Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks,
Rob

Comment: NetBIOS only works over an openvpn TAP/OSI Layer 2 VPN *or* if you use a WINS server (Windows Internet Name Server) to maintain a name database.  Do yourself a favour and just use the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: Getting broadcasts to the server

A conceptually simple, but difficult to implement solution is to have your laptop connect using a TAP VPN adapter instead of a TUN, and bridge it with the LAN interface of the VPN server. From the laptop's perspective it is directly connected to the same segment as the file server.

However, there are downsides beyond the complexity, and you really are trying to get a broadcast-based protocol to perform in a way it was not designed for.

#### Option 2: Local name resolution

If you're only interested in being able to type in the UNC path (`\\Server1\share`) and not browsing the local network/workgroup, then a [LMHOSTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977602.aspx) file on your laptop should be all that is required.

When you type in a UNC path for a server, the Windows client checks in four places (order depending on actual configuration and version) skipping those that are disabled/not configured:

- A WINS server, which has dynamic or static entries for the target. Since the target in this case is not a Windows device, you need to configure it to know where the WINS server is if you want dynamic entries, or set up the static ones yourself. WINS here is the protocol, since the WINS service itself is only available on Windows Server you can set this up using Samba, but it may not be worth the effort.
- A broadcast to the local network "Does anyone go by the name `Server1`?". By design, this broadcast does not cross routers (ie your VPN server).
- A query to the DNS server, possibly by adding your local network DNS suffix "Do you know who `Server1` is? How about `Server1.atmyhome.local`?".
- A LMHOSTS file, which provides the same information as a local broadcast or WINS query, but from disk so it is always available, consistent, and fast.

Since you have a small deployment, and it will change very infrequently, the LMHOSTS approach seems best.

Comment: Thanks - I was really hoping to see it appear automatically in the explorer window, rather than being able to type it in. So looks like not possible.